# Hadoop webhdfs curl create file

Tags: hadoop

I use ubuntu 12, Hadoop 1.0.3, i use webhdfs curl to create file.

```
curl -i -X PUT "http://localhost:50070/webhdfs/v1/test.txt?op=CREATE
```

or use the

```
curl -i -X PUT -T /home/hadoop/TestFile/test.txt "http://localhost:50070/webhdfs/v1/test?op=CREATE"
```

The two commend result is

> HTTP/1.1 307 TEMPORARY_REDIRECT

What set lack of the hdfs-site.xml? Or other permission not set?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the docs for Web HDFS, this is expected:

- http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/stable/webhdfs.html#CREATE

When you make the first put, you'll be given a temporary redirect URL of the datanode to which you can then issue another PUT command to actually upload the file into HDFS.

The document also explains the reasoning behind this 2-step create method:

> Note that the reason of having two-step create/append is for preventing clients to send out data before the redirect. This issue is addressed by the "Expect: 100-continue" header in HTTP/1.1; see RFC 2616, Section 8.2.3. Unfortunately, there are software library bugs (e.g. Jetty 6 HTTP server and Java 6 HTTP client), which do not correctly implement "Expect: 100-continue". The two-step create/append is a temporary workaround for the software library bugs.

Comment: you can't set it, the response from the name node in the first request is the redirect URL you need to perform the second PUT against (the data node on which the data will be stored)

Comment: @ChrisWhite- Can you do it on Hdp sandbox VM. The vm resurns redirect address to sandbox.hortonworks.com:8020 which i believe is not valid datanode address.

Comment: The link in the answer is dead now "Not Found
The requested URL /docs/stable/webhdfs.html was not found on this server."

Answer (score -1):

I know i am replying very late but anyone else looking for answers here will be able to see it.
Hi @Krishna Pandey this is the new link for WebHDFS 
https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.0.4/webhdfs.html#CREATE

You can refer to this blog for steps and commands https://wordpress.com/post/had00ping.wordpress.com/194

Comment: is there a way to get to the blog without signing on to wordpress?